# Fedora file permissions not taking effect

Tags: linux

I have a directory /models/ with the permissions

```
drw-rw-rw- 2 owner developers 4096 Jun 24 15:13 models
```

these were set with

```
sudo chmod -R 0666 *
```

My user has developers as the primary group (the same group as the file), but I cannot access the directory via the terminal or ftp.

```
[myUser@machine]$ id myUser
uid=503(myUser) gid=505(developers) groups=505(developers)
$ cd models 
-bash: cd: models: Permission denied
```

I had the same problem before the directory belonged to my group, and I even went so far as to restart the server, without any luck. How do I set permissions to this directory so that I and other members of the group developers can access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"executable" flag for directories means you can list the contents of that directory, so enable the executable flag:

```
chmod 777 models
```

Comment: Thank you- it is strange that all the guides I found on google don't mention this, when it is so simple and (now) obvious.

Comment: I haven't yet found a directory that warranted `777` permissions. `/tmp` and other public directories should be `1777` (set the [sticky bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit)), so that users cannot delete files owned by someone else. But `777` is begging for trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Directories need execute permission to be readable.

Answer (score 1):

Directories need execution rights to be traversable. So, if you set the r flag but not the x flag you can read the directory content but not go into it.